# Creating a list of images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a bunch of images of different resolution that I'd like to keep in a list.

Such that `list(1)` would be the first image, `list(2)` would be the second image, and so on.

I am using `impyramid` to create multiple resolution versions. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The only real way to do this (because your images could have different dimensions) is to keep a cell array of them:

```
list{1} = im1;
list{2} = im2;
```

Comment: Similar task here and your cell proposal worked (I used also preallocation img_list = cell(1,n)). Thanks